# process killed -- delete output file?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that runs on our shared web host. It does a dump of our mysql database and zips up the output file. Sometimes the mysqldump process gets killed, which leaves an incomplete sql file that still gets zipped. How do I get my script to 'notice' the killing and then delete the output file if the killing occurred?

---

Edit: here's the line from my script

```
nice -19 mysqldump -uuser -ppassword -h database.hostname.com --skip-opt --all --complete-insert --add-drop-table database_name > ~/file/system/path/filename.sql
```

And here's what I get *on occasion* from my buddy Cron:

```
/home/user/backup_script.bash: line 17: 12611 Killed                       nice -19 mysqldump -uuser -ppassword -h database.hostname.com --skip-opt --all --complete-insert --add-drop-table database_name > ~/file/system/path/filename.sql
```

So when this happens, I want to just delete the filename.sql, becuase it will have some number of inserts, but not all. I know in bash there is someway to capture the output state of a command, true or false, and then if it's false, do something.

Comment: This is a programming question, it will probably be migrated to stackoverflow.com. Make an account there and associate it with your SuperUser account so that you can take ownership of the question after it moves. EDIT: You should probably edit your post to include the source code from your script so that people can answer it more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If mysqldump gets killed it will have an exit code != 0:

```
if ! mysqldump ...;then 
  rm ...
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `ps` or `pgrep` to see if the process is still running based on its name. Or you could use `lsof` on the SQL file to see if a process is accessing the file. However, if the process completes normally, that "open" connection will no longer be there.

Comment: I don't want to do this manually; I want the script to do this.

Comment: @user151841: There's no reason at all that a script can't do what I described.